# Performance Counter Logs on IIS 6 Web Servers

Tags: iis-6, performance-monitoring

Can you please suggest or point me to a place that suggests the best Performance Monitor Counters to monitor on a Web Server running IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003. We have a number of websites on these servers and I would like to start performing more detailed reporting on how these servers are performing. At the moment we are monitoring the basics, such as CPU, Memory, Bandwidth etc, but I am sure there are plenty of specific IIS / ASP.NET counters that could be used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 documents that should be helpful. The first is a general IIS "Suggested Performance Counters to Watch" list that includes baseline ideal values. The second adds some suggested counters for monitoring ASP.Net performance.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782186(WS.10).aspx](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/97d0872a-96b3-41e4-8997-b174a9dbb87f.mspx?mfr=true)
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/97d0872a-96b3-41e4-8997-b174a9dbb87f.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

Check this out http://blogs.msdn.com/tom/archive/2008/05/02/asp-net-tips-what-to-gather-to-troubleshoot-part-1-high-cpu.aspx

Comment: thanks! but this is not quite what I am after. I would prefer something more specific than just adding "ALL COUNTERS" for the processes hosting the application.